# DateTimePicker блокировка дат

Tags: c#, winforms

Как в C# заблокировать даты в `DateTimePicker` через каждые 7 дней от начала года и все праздники?

Comment: WPF или WinForms?

Comment: @VladD WinForms

Comment: вероятно, стоит уточнить, какие именно «праздники» подразумеваются.

Comment: @Сергей74rus не думаю что это возможно в `WinForms` с стандартным `DateTimePicker`.

Comment: на EnSO тоже говорят что это невозможно и рекомендуют использовать аналогичный компонент из WPF или DevExpress. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2364096/5796587 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/27319756/5796587

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так. Праздники добавить ручками. И 1янв.+7дней не очень хорошо. Наверное хотели все ВС. Ну тогда надо еще определить первое ВС года.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly List<DateTime> _blockedDates = new List<DateTime>(); // List of blocked dates
    private DateTime Dt { get; set; }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Dt=DateTime.Now;
        var d= new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,1,1);
        //Fill blocked dates with 1/1 + each 7 days
        while (d.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
        {
            _blockedDates.Add(d);
            d=d.AddDays(7);
        }
    }

    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTimePicker ctl = (sender as DateTimePicker);
        if (ctl == null) return;
        if (BlockedDate(ctl.Value))ctl.Value = Dt;
        else Dt = ctl.Value;
    }

    private bool BlockedDate(DateTime value)
    {
        return _blockedDates.Any(x => x.Date == value.Date);
    }
}
```